# Unrealscript Vector Invert function

Tags: udk

Could I please get an example of the correct syntax for calling the

> Invert ( out vector X, out vector Y, out vector Z )

function

Comment: Simple question doesn't mean it's not a fit for the site, I don't see anything else wrong with it. Sorry about the people down voting without comment.

Comment: From the [docs](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:UnrealScript_Language_Reference/Language_Functionality): "Inverts a coordinate system specified by three axis vectors."  I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.  Maybe it'll clue in someone else.

Comment: Sounds like it's doing a matrix inverse on the upper 3x3 and returning them as individual axes instead of all matrixed up.

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't find and examples of that function specifically, we can look at the [`out`](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MasteringUnrealScriptFunctions.html#Out) parameter modifier to get an idea of how this function might work.

In the example:

```
Function Clamp(Out Int Value, Int Min, Int Max) {   
    if( Value < Min)
      Value = Min;
    else if( Value > Max)
      Value = Max; 
}
```

And it's usage:

```
Clamp(Health, 0, 100);
```

We see that for the `out` parameter, we need to pass in variable that's been defined already (similar to other languages that have an `out` parameter modifier). Based off that, I would assume the correct syntax for the `Invert` function would be something like:

```
var Vector xVec;
var Vector yVec;
var Vector zVec;

//set vectors to something to be inverted

Invert ( xVec, yVec, zVec );
```

Where a `Vector` is defined as:

```
struct Vector
{
    var float X;
    var float Y;
    var float Z;
};
```